# CodeIgniter - Files aren't refreshed.

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, refresh

Can anybody tell me why modifications in my php files are not directly considered ?

For example, if I remove a line throwing an error inside one of my controllers, I will see the same error when I refresh my page, although the line does not exist anymore !

The cache folder is empty, so what's the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: did you save the file.. is your changes are exist in that controller. Are you sure the error is exist on your removed line. Please update your error details

Comment: @Sundar of course I always save the files...

Comment: can you update what error you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a Cache problem, I would put my money on it is your development stack causing it.

Are you using MAMP?

Comment: Go to preferences, php and make sure cache is "off" or "disabled" and if that doesn't help, try changing PHP version.

Comment: Yes ! Caching was disabled but I switched from PHP 5.5.3 to PHP 5.2.17, and modifications in php files are now instant ! Thank you :)